# R package check stuck on "checking use of S3 registration ..."

Tags: r, r-package, cran, r-s3

I am developing an R package which I plan to upload to CRAN.

Upon checking the tarball created with `R CMD BUILD`, I try to use `R CMD CHECK` as follows:

```
R CMD CHECK my_package.tar.gz --as-cran
```

This normally works smoothly. However, in this case, it is stuck on `checking use of S3 registration` and has been there for several hours. I've never experienced this before; here's the partial output I see:

```
...
 * checking package subdirectories ... OK
 * checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
 * checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
 * checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
 * checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
 * checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
 * checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
 * checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
 * checking use of S3 registration ...
```

(1) What does `checking use of S3 registration` really mean?

(2) More importantly, why would it be stuck here? How could I fix this issue?

Any insight or help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those arriving via Google as I did, it is likely to be an XQuartz problem. Duncan Murdoch documented how to fix it on the R-Sig-Mac mail list.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2021-February/013952.html

Following his instructions and reinstalling XQuartz worked for me to resolve the issue with S3 registration checking.

Comment: Thanks for this. I suspected it was an XQuartz problem. I've marked your answer as correct for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with R 4.1 (2021-01-14 r79827) and RStudio 1.3.1093 or RStudio 1.4.1573.
MacOSX Big Sur 11.2.1
It blocks at the same stage as yours even for package without any change since the last test.
Marc

Comment: I've never found an answer to this.